# Laravel Configuration Multidimensional array for different Environment

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array, configuration, environment

version: laravel-4.2.11

Environment: production && local

production, local all have a file named 'app.php'

in production :

```
'test-key'   =>  [
    1   =>  [
        'customer_service'  =>  [],
        'customer_manage'   =>  []
    ],
    3   =>  [
        'customer_service'  =>  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'customer_manage'   =>  []
    ],
],
```

in local :

```
'test-key'   =>  [
    1   =>  [
        'customer_service'  =>  [],
        'customer_manage'   =>  []
    ],
    3   =>  [
        'customer_service'  =>  ['b', 'e'],
        'customer_manage'   =>  ['b', 'e']
    ],
],
```

when i use `Config::get('app.test-key')[3]['customer_service']` in local environment, i get the result: `['b', 'e', 'c', 'd']`

this is not expected.

any body can tell me why this happend?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel detects which environment you are working in through its `bootstrap/start.php` file.

The best way to go about this, is to set a **Server** variable in your PHP configuration.

Here's a sample of my environment detection code in the `start.php` file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['LARAVEL_ENV']))
    {
        return $_SERVER['LARAVEL_ENV'];
    }
    else
    {
        return 'development';
    }
});
```

`$_SERVER['LARAVEL_ENV']` values would normally be either 'production' or 'development'.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i have config the $env in the start.php:$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),

));

Comment: And what folders do you have in your `app/config`?

Comment: a folder named 'local'